# SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard - expired evaluation, but I didn't install evaluation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've been working with Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard and SQL Server Management Studio on this machine for months.

Suddenly, when I try to launch Management Studio it tells me that it's expired and I can't access my data.

"Evaluation period has expired. For information on how to upgrade your evaluation software please go to http://www.microsoft.com/sql/howtobuy"

I've been working on a project since around late July that required me to install SQL Server 2008 R2 Express alongside Standard.  Could that be related?

What's aggravating is that none of these are "evaluation" copies - so I don't know where that complaint is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently having a similar issue, and found this that might help you

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971268

It gives you two options, to upgrade to SP1 and/or to edit a registry key.